# Check textarea or input have some special word in need

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax-highlighting

I want to make a coding area for my website,and I need to make it having color coded(syntax highlighting),and I Google so hard,but I still can't find the right answer for me, and here is my code now.
And I'm using `Jquery`

HTML:

```
<textarea class="CodeArea codingground">

  <div class="HelloMate">

  </div>

</textarea>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

$('.CodeArea.codingground').on('input',function(){
  var code = $(this).val();

  if (code.indexOf('class')>=0) {
    $( "textarea:contains('class')" ).css( "color", "red" );
  }

});

});
```

Comment: I strong recommend to use editor such as https://ace.c9.io/

Comment: How would you like to do that? Similar to `Stack Overflow`?

Comment: Wait, highlight and your code are 2 diffrent things. Do you want to show validation error or you want to let the user enter code and highlight it?

Comment: let the user enter code and highlight it

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a `textarea`.

You can use the `<code>` tag in conjunction with the `contenteditable` attribute. Some Javascript and you'll get what you want, even though you should consider to use a library for stuff like that.

```js
var text = jQuery('code').text();
text = text.replace('class', '<span style="color: red">class</span>');
jQuery('code').html(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code contenteditable="true">
    class Blubb() {

    }
</code>
```